# DocuSign CLM download PDF document

Tags: pdf, docusignapi

I'm following the api documentation trying to download a pdf document into PDF. I'm trying to simulate this in Postman first, before delving in code.
I have used many of their apis successfully, but can't get the download one. The docs say to download a document by id:

https://apidocsqana11.springcm.com/apidocs#!/Content/Content_Get

> Implementation Notes Specify file type of document (image, PDF) in
> ACCEPT header. Do not specify an ACCEPT header for native format
>
> Response Class string
>
> Response Content Type: application/json

So, I tried adding Accept and content-type as application/pdf in my postman to see if I will get a pdf document, but keep getting the response as normal json. I'm trying to get back a pdf doc not json response.

[image]

Comment: can you point out which documentation you're following? this looks like the CLM API (SpringCM in URL) so I wonder if you can explain what you're doing and we can look up if the documentation may need updates

Comment: @InbarGazit I added the url and little more explanation of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the 'REST API - Download Endpoint:' which is typically like https://apidownload<>.springcm.com - in your case could be - [https://apidownloaddocsqana11.springcm.com/v2/{{accountId}}/documents/{id}](https://apidownloaddocsqana11.springcm.com/v2/%7B%7BaccountId%7D%7D/documents/%7Bid%7D).

In Postman, Raw response could be random characters, but you can click the dropdown next to 'Send' button and click 'Send & Download' which will download the document for you.

Please mark the comment as an answer if it worked.